# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

```
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SummaryStatistics");  
    JavaSparkContext spark = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

    JavaRDD<String> textFile = spark.textFile(args[0]); 

    JavaRDD<Vector> points = textFile.map(new ParsePoint());

    RowMatrix mat = new RowMatrix(points.rdd());
    MultivariateStatisticalSummary summary = mat.computeColumnSummaryStatistics();

    System.out.println(summary.mean()); 

    JavaRDD<Vector> result=(JavaRDD<Vector>) summary.mean(); // ***** Throwing error****
    result.saveAsTextFile(args[1]);
```

How can we store the result summary.mean() in a file. Above approach (casting summary.mean() in a vector RDD) is not working and giving that exception.

Comment: Why do you do not use ObjectOutputStream for saving summary.mean();?

Comment: I am using HDFS as source. ObjectOutputStream can't create/modify file in HDFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just *cast* any object of type X into a `JavaRDD<X>`. You need to create an RDD using SparkContext's `parallelize` method. So - if you really want to use Spark to save a *single vector*, you can do it by creating an RDD based on a single-record collection:

```
List<Vector> oneItemList = new LinkedList<>();
oneItemList.add(summary.mean());
JavaRDD<Vector> result = spark.parallelize(oneItemList);
result.saveAsTextFile(args[1]);
```

But that's on overkill (using Spark to save one record).

Alternatively, you can save HDFS files using HDFS API, something like:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.*;

Path path = new Path(args[1]);
Configuration conf = new Configuration(); // set your HDFS properties if needed
FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.get(conf); 
// (assuming Java 7 or higher)
try (FSDataOutputStream out = fileSystem.create(path)) {
    out.writeBytes(summary.mean().toString());
    out.flush();
}
```

NOTE: Examples use Java 7, Hadoop V2.4, Spark V1.5.2 - but APIs are stable so shouldn't change much for other recent versions.